# Vbox Parent, Pane Child overlapping other components javafx

Tags: java, javafx-8

Hey all I am new to java and javafx trying to learn them. I am currently trying to do a problem where the user inputs values for two circles (the center and radius of circle). It is supposed to then show the circles, and display what they are doing, such as they are equal, one is contained in the other, etc.

To do this I used a vbox, and I am attempting to draw the circles using a pane, and implementing the pane into the vbox.  Here is my code:

```
 public class Shapes extends Application {

  @Override
  public void start(Stage stage) {

  createTextField();
  VBox root = new VBox(); 
  root.setSpacing(10);
  Pane pane = new Pane();
  Color blue = new Color(1,0,0,1);
  Color red = new Color(0,0,1,1);
  Circle circle1 = createCircle(50, 50, 50, red);
  Circle circle2 = createCircle(50, 50, 200, blue);
  pane.getChildren().addAll(circle1, circle2);
  root.getChildren().addAll(label0, label1, label2, tField, label3, label4, pane);
  Scene scene = new Scene(root, 1000 , 1000);
  stage.setTitle("Spatial Relations Demo by");
  stage.setScene(scene);
  stage.show();
  }


  public static void main(String[] args) {
  Application.launch(args);
  }

  Label label0, label1, label2, label3, label4;
  TextField tField;


  public void createTextField()
  {
   label0 = new Label();
   label0.setText("Spatial Relations Demo");

   label1 = new Label();
   label1.setText("                              ");
   label1.setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER);

   label2 = new Label();
   label2.setText("Input Circles: x1 y1 r1 x2 y2 r2 ");
   label2.setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER);

   label3 = new Label();
   label3.setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER);

   label4 = new Label();
   label4.setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER);

  tField = new TextField();
  tField.setOnAction(new TextFieldHandler());
 }

  public class TextFieldHandler implements EventHandler<ActionEvent> {
  public void handle( ActionEvent e)
  {
  String str = tField.getText();
  int x1, y1, r1, x2, y2, r2;

  Scanner scanner = new Scanner(str);
  x1 = scanner.nextInt();
  y1 = scanner.nextInt();
  r1 = scanner.nextInt();

  x2 = scanner.nextInt();
  y2 = scanner.nextInt();
  r2 = scanner.nextInt();

  tField.setText( "" );
  String str1 = str.format("Input is: " + x1 + " " + y1 + " " + r1 + " " + x2 + " " + y2 + " " + r2);
  label3.setText(str1);

 double d = sqrt((x1-x2)*(x1-x2)+(y1-y2)*(y1-y2));

 if ((x1==x2) & (y1==y2) & (r1==r2))
   label4.setText( " The circles are equal.");
 else if (d >= (r1+r2))
   label4.setText( " The circle interiors are disjoint.");
 else if (d <= (r2-r1))
   label4.setText( " Circle1 is inside Circle2.");
 else if (d <= (r1-r2))
   label4.setText( " Circle2 is inside Circle1.");
 else
   label4.setText( " The circles overlap.");
}
}

 public Circle createCircle(int x, int y, int r, Color color)
  {
    Circle circle = new Circle();
    circle.setRadius(r);
    circle.setCenterX(x);
    circle.setCenterY(y);
    circle.setStroke(color);
    circle.setFill(null);

    return circle;  
  }



}
```

As of right now I just have implemented some test numbers to draw the circles, but I am still trying to figure out how to get the user inputted numbers as my circle parameters. I was not sure how to get the pane to work properly. Any tips or advice would be greatly appreciated thanks! I tried to post an image to show my output but I guess I dont have enough reputation for it. My circles are overlapping everything instead of staying below the labels and textfield. I cant seem to figure out how to keep them below those items in the vbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your red circle (the one with the color you called `blue` ;) ) has bounds that extend into negative coordinate ranges in both x- and y-directions (it has center (50, 50) and radius 200). Hence it extends beyond the bounds of the pane.

If you want to make sure the pane doesn't paint outside of its bounds, you can set a clip that is bound to its size:

```
    Rectangle clip = new Rectangle(0, 0, 0, 0);
    clip.widthProperty().bind(pane.widthProperty());
    clip.heightProperty().bind(pane.heightProperty());
    pane.setClip(clip);
```

To update the circles, you just have to make them instance variables instead of local to the `start` method, and update their centers and radii:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.scene.text.TextAlignment;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Shapes extends Application {

    private Label label0, label1, label2, label3, label4;
    private TextField tField;

    private Circle circle1 ;
    private Circle circle2 ; 

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {

        createTextField();
        VBox root = new VBox();
        root.setSpacing(10);
        Pane pane = new Pane();
        Color blue = new Color(1, 0, 0, 1);
        Color red = new Color(0, 0, 1, 1);
        circle1 = createCircle(50, 50, 50, red);
        circle2 = createCircle(50, 50, 200, blue);
        pane.getChildren().addAll(circle1, circle2);

        // If desired:

        // Rectangle clip = new Rectangle(0, 0, 0, 0);
        // clip.widthProperty().bind(pane.widthProperty());
        // clip.heightProperty().bind(pane.heightProperty());
        // pane.setClip(clip);


        root.getChildren().addAll(label0, label1, label2, tField, label3,
                label4, pane);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 1000, 1000);
        stage.setTitle("Spatial Relations Demo by");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }


    public void createTextField() {
        label0 = new Label();
        label0.setText("Spatial Relations Demo");

        label1 = new Label();
        label1.setText("                              ");
        label1.setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER);

        label2 = new Label();
        label2.setText("Input Circles: x1 y1 r1 x2 y2 r2 ");
        label2.setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER);

        label3 = new Label();
        label3.setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER);

        label4 = new Label();
        label4.setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER);

        tField = new TextField();
        tField.setOnAction(new TextFieldHandler());
    }

    public class TextFieldHandler implements EventHandler<ActionEvent> {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
            String str = tField.getText();
            int x1, y1, r1, x2, y2, r2;

            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(str);
            x1 = scanner.nextInt();
            y1 = scanner.nextInt();
            r1 = scanner.nextInt();

            x2 = scanner.nextInt();
            y2 = scanner.nextInt();
            r2 = scanner.nextInt();

            circle1.setCenterX(x1);
            circle1.setCenterY(y1);
            circle1.setRadius(r1);
            circle2.setCenterX(x2);
            circle2.setCenterY(y2);
            circle2.setRadius(r2);

            tField.setText("");
            String str1 = String.format("Input is: " + x1 + " " + y1 + " " + r1
                    + " " + x2 + " " + y2 + " " + r2);
            label3.setText(str1);

            double d = Math.sqrt((x1 - x2) * (x1 - x2) + (y1 - y2) * (y1 - y2));

            if ((x1 == x2) & (y1 == y2) & (r1 == r2))
                label4.setText(" The circles are equal.");
            else if (d >= (r1 + r2))
                label4.setText(" The circle interiors are disjoint.");
            else if (d <= (r2 - r1))
                label4.setText(" Circle1 is inside Circle2.");
            else if (d <= (r1 - r2))
                label4.setText(" Circle2 is inside Circle1.");
            else
                label4.setText(" The circles overlap.");

            scanner.close();
        }
    }

    public Circle createCircle(int x, int y, int r, Color color) {
        Circle circle = new Circle();
        circle.setRadius(r);
        circle.setCenterX(x);
        circle.setCenterY(y);
        circle.setStroke(color);
        circle.setFill(null);

        return circle;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer James! I actually just figured it out myself a good 2 minutes ago haha. I ended up using a gridpane to align them and it has seemed to do the trick!